# basic terminology

Tags: terminology

1. 

Suppose we have two computers whose performance is P1 and P2 respectively when P2=d⋅P1. What is the most accurate name for d? Is the term "transition factor" appropriate? Additional suggestions are welcome.

2. Suppose we have a computer whose performance is affected by two factors F1 and F2. We are interested in presenting their common effect by a single number, d, as follows:
   d⋅F1+(1−d)⋅F2.
   What is the most accurate name for d in such a case?

Thanks in advance, Ami

Comment: Probably depends on what d actually means in the real world. E.g.. is F1 the GPU load and F2 the CPU load? You might say that (d*100%) of the problem "can be executed on the GPU"

Comment: OK. Suppose as you suggest that F1 and F2 represent the loads of the CPU and the GPU. Then, d⋅F1 + (1 − d) ⋅F2 is the mean when d = 0.5. But, for example, since we are giving greater weight to the GPU then we will define d = 0.7. Now the question is how do we call d? For example, does "fitting parameter" sound appropriate? Maybe something else?